# Command Line Arguments count in C

Tags: c, command-line-arguments

I have written this program in C which takes command line arguments and displays it along with  argument count. But the arguments one more than the number of arguments typed.

```
#include<stdio.h>
 void main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {
 int i=0;
 for(i=0;argv[1][i]!='\0';i++)
 {
  if(argv[1][i]>='a' && argv[1][i]>='z')
  {
   argv[1][i]=argv[1][i];
  }
   }
  printf("%s",argv[1]);
  printf("\n");
  printf("%d",argc);
 }
```

The argument I pass: upper abracadabra . It gives me a count as 3. Any reason. Thanks in advance

Comment: I dunno about you, but my first thought would have been to *see what the args' values are*.  In this case, on every platform i use, that would clear things right up.

Comment: btw what should your loop do here?

Comment: Nothing relevant here. Just added it to mark as end of arguments

Comment: Not trying to nitpick, but `main()` should return `int`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ever wondered what `printf("%s",argv[0])` would do? C array indexing start with 0. That's the solution to your question.The argv[0] holds the program name that's being executed,and is the first argument(for eg, a.out)

Comment: Note: not "the file that's being executed", but "the program name".  The two may not be the same on some platforms or in some cases.

Answer (score 4):

Remember that C arrays are zero-based so valid indices run [0..argc].  Your program skips checking `argv[0]`.

In addition to the arguments you specify, `argv[0]` is set to your program name (or NULL if the platform can't determine the name).

If you wanted to check the command line args, you could do something like

```
int i;
for (i=0; i<argc; i++) {
    printf("argv[%d] = %s\n", i, argv[i]);
}
```

Comment: program name. would that be the filename?

Comment: @simonc: It's not *defined* to be the filename of the executable.  Its actual value is implementation-specific.

Comment: @Koneri Taking into account cHao's comment, `argv[0]` is specified to be the program name (C99 s5.1.2.2.1 Program startup).  The program name may very well be the filename of your executable program but this isn't guaranteed.

Answer (score 1):

Actually argv[0] holds the name of the program and uses it when your program forks a child.
Whenever you call fork() in C,it produces a child process with the same name as the parent process e.g a.out. Child takes the name of its parent from argv[0]. So every thing comes with a purpose right.

Answer (score 0):

This is because `argv` does not hold command line arguments. It holds full command line. First one is the command and the rest are arguments.